# How to get single Dataframe instead of multiple Dataframes while converting list of dictionaries to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, dictionary

I tried many methods to get single dataframe instead of multiple dataframes

while converting list of separate dictionaries to dataframe it is creating number of separate dataframes

here is the examples of list of separate dictionaries data rows_data output:

```
[{'case_id': 22, 'case_subject': 'followup'}, {'case_id': 22, 'case_subject': 'rma'}, {'case_id': 22, 'case_subject': 'ticket'}, {'case_id': 22, 'case_subject': '61555'}][{'case_id': 26, 'case_subject': 'c'}, {'case_id': 26, 'case_subject': 'ge'},{'case_id':26,'case_subject': 'app'}, {'case_id': 26, 'case_subject': 'logs'},{'case_id':26, 'case_subject': 'request'}][{'case_id': 30, 'case_subject': 'refund'}, {'case_id': 30, 'case_subject': 'request'}, {'case_id': 30, 'case_subject': 'return'},{'case_id': 30, 'case_subject': 'refund'}, {'case_id': 30, 'case_subject': 'pending'}, {'case_id': 30, 'case_subject': 'partial'}, {'case_id': 30, 'case_subject': 'payment'}][{'case_id': 34, 'case_subject': 'unable'}, {'case_id': 34, 'case_subject': 'control'},{'case_id': 34, 'case_subject': 'devices'}, {'case_id': 34, 'case_subject': 'via'}, {'case_id': 34, 'case_subject': 'mfg'}, {'case_id': 34, 'case_subject': 'configured'}, {'case_id': 34, 'case_subject': 'devices'}][{'case_id': 38, 'case_subject': 'trouble'}, {'case_id': 38, 'case_subject': 'connecting'}, {'case_id': 38, 'case_subject': 'alexa'}]
```

after that i tried to convert dataframe with counts of repeated words, hre is the code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rows_data)
    out = df.assign(case_subject =df['case_subject'].str.split())\
            .explode('case_subject').value_counts()\
            .rename('Case_Subject_Split_Count').reset_index()
    print(out)
```

after that I got output like below:

```
case_id case_subject  Case_Subject_Split_Count
0       22        61555                         1
1       22     followup                         1
2       22          rma                         1
3       22       ticket                         1
   case_id case_subject  Case_Subject_Split_Count
0       26          app                         1
1       26            c                         1
2       26           ge                         1
3       26         logs                         1
4       26      request                         1
   case_id case_subject  Case_Subject_Split_Count
0       30       refund                         2
1       30      partial                         1
2       30      payment                         1
3       30      pending                         1
4       30      request                         1
5       30       return                         1
   case_id case_subject  Case_Subject_Split_Count
0       34      devices                         2
1       34   configured                         1
2       34      control                         1
3       34          mfg                         1
4       34       unable                         1
5       34          via                         1
   case_id case_subject  Case_Subject_Split_Count
0       38        alexa                         1
1       38   connecting                         1
2       38      trouble                         1
```

but i need one dataframe not separate dataframe like above

i want output like below

```
case_id case_subject  Case_Subject_Split_Count
     22        61555                         1
     22     followup                         1
     22          rma                         1
     22       ticket                         1
     26          app                         1
     26            c                         1
     26           ge                         1
     26         logs                         1
     26      request                         1
     30       refund                         2
     30      partial                         1
     30      payment                         1
     30      pending                         1
     30      request                         1
     30       return                         1
     34      devices                         2
     34   configured                         1
     34      control                         1
     34          mfg                         1
     34       unable                         1
     34          via                         1
     38        alexa                         1
     38   connecting                         1
     38      trouble                         1
```

can anyone please help me out how can i overcome this issue

please read question carefully before answering, thanks..

Comment: Are data separated by `,` between inner lists like in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: you can use `append` to variable outside loop:

```
conn.commit() 
data = cur.fetchall() 

output_data = [] 

for row in data: 
    string = str(row[1]) 
    pp2 =''.join(e for e in string if (e.isalnum() or e.isspace())) 
    pp1 = re.sub(' ',' ',pp2).lower() 
    li = list(pp1.split(" "))
    dec_cnt = li 
    zipped = list(zip(li, (row[0] for _ in li))) 
    
    for row1 in zipped: 
        each_row= {"case_id":row1[1],"case_subject":row1[0]} 
        output_data.append(each_row)

out = (pd.DataFrame(output_data)
         .assign(case_subject =lambda x: x['case_subject'].str.split())\
         .explode('case_subject').value_counts()\
         .rename('Case_Subject_Split_Count')
         .reset_index()
         .sort_values(['case_id','Case_Subject_Split_Count'],
                      ascending=[True, False],
                      ignore_index=False))
```

Comment: The Data is not separated list from output
[{'case_id': 6, 'case_subject': 'reg'}]
[{'case_id': 10, 'case_subject': 'rma'}]
[{'case_id': 6, 'case_subject': 'non}]
[{'case_id': 10, 'case_subject': 'no'}]
so we don't have comma separated list

Comment: So are invalid? Because if use `pd.DataFrame(rows_data)` get error `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Comment: now i didn't get any error it creates separate dataframes,
is there any way where i can add my separated list of dicts to one list

Comment: So your code is different? Or some loop is missing in question?

Comment: actually i'm trying to get data from database once i fetched data it is getting separate lists it self after that i'm doing some kind of operations to get rows_data format after that i'm trying to convert into data frame again i'm loading another sql table

Comment: conn.commit()
data = cur.fetchall()   
for row in data:  
    string = str(row[1])   
    pp2 =''.join(e for e in string if (e.isalnum() or e.isspace()))
    pp1 = re.sub('  ',' ',pp2).lower()
    li = list(pp1.split(" ")) 
    dec_cnt = li 
    zipped = list(zip(li, (row[0] for _ in li)))
    rows_data = []
    for row1 in zipped:
        each_row= {"case_id":row1[1],"case_subject":row1[0]}
        rows_data.append(each_row)

Comment: Answer was edited.

Comment: thanks for answering but case_id not getting in sorting order

    case_id   case_subject  Case_Subject_Split_Count
0        34        devices                         2
1        30         refund                         2
2         2              1                         1
3        30        request                         1
4        26             ge                         1
5        26           logs                         1

Comment: Can you add `.sort_values('case_id', ignore_index=False)` to end of answer?

Comment: added getting values now sorting order, how to remove extra index, that 2,25,24,
 case_id   case_subject  Case_Subject_Split_Count
2         2              1                         1
25        2     validation                         1
24        2           test                         1
23        2        connect                         1

Comment: how to remove index in dataframe, now i'm getting index also in dataframe so data is not looks good to load in Database, can you please suggest

Comment: Do you think `print(out.to_string(index=False))` ?

Comment: or need convert to file without index? Like `out.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)` ?